# C++ - Overload with template policy class

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, policy, c++98

I have a code that produces a sequence of numbers and I want to do different online post-processing on those numbers. I am trying to use a policy-based design to achieve this, like so:

```
// This is a general class to integrate some quantity
class QuantityIntegrator
{
public:
    QuantityIntegrator () : result(0) {}
    double getResult() const {return result;}
    void setResult(const double val) {result = val;}

private:
    double result;
};

// This is my policy class
// A dummy integrator for this example, but there can be others for
// arithmetic average, root-mean-square, etc...
struct NoIntegrator : public QuantityIntegrator
{
    // The function that characterizes a policy
    void addValue(double val, double) {setResult(val);}
};

// Interface
// This is needed because I want to create a vector of OutputQuantity, which
// is templated
class OutputQuantity_I
{
public:
    // These are the functions that I want to override
    virtual double getResult() const {cout << "Calling forbidden function getResult"; return -123456;}
    virtual void addValue(double, double) {cout << "Calling forbidden function addValue";}

    // A method that produces some number sequence
    double evaluate() const
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

// The general class for output quantities, from which concrete output
// quantities will inherit
template <typename IntegratorPolicy>
struct OutputQuantity : public OutputQuantity_I,
                        public IntegratorPolicy
{
};

// One particular output quantity, whose template I can specialize to decide
// how to integrate it
template <typename IntegratorPolicy>
struct SomeOutput : public OutputQuantity<IntegratorPolicy>
{
};

typedef std::vector<OutputQuantity_I*> OutputQuantityList;


int main()
{
    SomeOutput s;
    OutputQuantityList l;
    l.push_back(&s);

    // Here OutputQuantity_I::addValue is called, instead of
    // IntegratorPolicy::addValue
    l[0]->addValue(1,2); 
}
```

So my question is: how can I get the code to call the method `addValue` defined by `IntegratorPolicy`?

P.s. I'm bound to use C++98.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to call non-static functions in a static way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I gave it a thought and found a solution myself. It makes me realize that the problem is actually stupid, but I'm going to post it as someone else might run into it. Inside `OutputQuantity` I overrode `addValue` to explicitly call `IntegratorPolicy::addValue`, writing what is basically a wrapper function.